# When to use Which Exchange in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have read so many articles regarding exchanges in RabbitMQ. 
But I couldn't find any useful article which explains about usecases of each exchange.
all they are saying is

**Direct Exchange** - Binding key and routing key should be same.

**Topic Exchange** - Routing key should match the routing pattern of the binding key.

**Fanout Exchange** - All the queues which are bounds to that particular exchange will get the message.

**Header Exchange** - headers should match the key.

can any one explain each exchange and usecases of it in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the choice of exchange type to use is pretty much driven by your use case, it your responsibility to choose the exchange type that suits you best.

Here are some examples:

1. Lets say you want a **broadcast** (you have multiple instances of the applications that are supposed to receive the message). For example, something happens in the system (resource becomes available, cache should be invalidated, you name it) and you want that all instances will know it. Then your first bet will be using fanout exchange.
2. Another example. You want to **unicast**: send a message and you have multiple consumers, but you want that only one consumer will get a message and will attempt to process it. In this case, you can't use fan-out exchange and you'll opt for other types of exchange (like direct exchange for example).

All-in-all I believe you should be interested to read [this article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) that describes various concepts of fairly rich amqp protocol and provides use case examples for different types of exchanges.